# Is there a way to get the scene history from react-native-router-flux?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have a situation where I need to compare the current scene to the scene the user would go back to if I called Actions.pop();

Basically if transitioning between certain scenes I need to fire a bunch of actions to get the store state setup for the scene that the user is going back to. This happens because I have some routes that use the same component and therefore after the current scene is popped the store is still reflecting the old scene.

Is there a way in react-native-router-flux to get the scene history?

I thought about adding something to my navigation reducer, but I expected react-native-router-flux to have something for this already...it has to know what it's popping back to doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

With the v4, you can do it now :

```
const reducerCreate = (params) => {
  const defaultReducer = new Reducer(params) // import from RNRF
  return (state, action) => {
    console.log('Action :', action)
    console.log('State :', state)
    return defaultReducer(state, action)
  }
}
```

And then in your Router

```
<Router
  createReducer={reducerCreate}>
```